How much moving water in a grid cell will spill up into a higher adjacent cell?
I am trying to simulate an ocean-scale fluid event. Due to the scale, the existing techniques I am aware of are prohibitive, so I am trying to code a simpler model which is correct in the essential details, specifically conservation of mass and momentum. Certain aspects (diffusion, vorticity) are not important to me.
Dividing the world into grid cells, each perhaps many metres, or tens of metres, across:

each cell has a height of land, and a height of water
each cell also has the velocity/momentum of the water

The essential question is how much fluid flows between each cell per time step.
When water flows into adjacent water, I can advect it trivially.
When a high-water cell flows into a lower-water cell, I can use Torricelli's law to calculate how much water pours across unimpeded, and the momentum it gains.
The question is what happens when a low-land cell flows into a higher-land cell. If the water flows with enough momentum it can "climb" the wall
How do I calculate the volume and momentum of the water in each cell in the subsequent time step?

